# Why is my WPF Command not firing?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have this XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Foo.UserControls.Bar"
             x:Name="FooBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <StackPanel>
        <WrapPanel Margin="4,0,0,0">
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=CreateCommand, ElementName=FooBar}">
                <TextBlock>Create</TextBlock>
            </Button>
```

with this code-behind (removed `using`s):

```
namespace Foo.UserControls
{
    public partial class Bar : UserControl
    {
        public DelegateCommand CreateCommand { get; private set; }

        public Bar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CreateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Create);
        }

        private void Create(object action)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("foo");
        }
    }
}
```

Both with debugger and console logging, it doesn't seem to ever fire. The odd thing is that the binding seems to be just fine, because it does not log any errors to the output. If I purposely break the binding I do get a binding error, but with the above binding I do not get any errors yet it never fires.

Comment: Try to set `DataContext = this` in the constructor after you created the command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try putting `CreateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Create);` before `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: @Default The control creates its binding in the `InitializeComponent()` method and at that time CreateCommand is unassigned. The user either needs to move the assignment before `InitializeComponent()` or raise the property changed event after the command is assigned.